# shopping-content api 403 error permission denied

Tags: google-api, google-shopping-api, google-shopping

I'm having a problem with the only limited access methods in shopping-content Api, my role in the account is owner but i'm getting 403 error permission denied
[403 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZtR7.png)

Answer (score 0):

Limited access means that the method is only available to certain accounts. The problem is that the method is not enabled for your account.

If you are talking about the order related methods, you can try enabling the "Buy on Google" program on your account. For other methods, you can try reaching out to support and ask to have your account whitelisted.